# How to achieve zero downtime redeployment in Node.js

Tags: node.js, deployment, gulp, forever, pm2

What is the easiest way to achieve zero downtime for my Node.js application?

I have an app that requires the following steps for redeployment:

- `npm install`
- `node_modules/.bin/bower install`
- `node_modules/.bin/gulp`

The result of these operations is the ready-to-run application in the generated by the `gulpfile.js` directory named `build`. In this directory I have a currently-running instance of the same application (currently launched via [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) like this -- `forever start server.js`).

As far as I know, it is not possible to achieve zero downtime via `forever` module, so I decided to choose another way to do it.

I saw [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) but I found it very complex tbh (prove me wrong if you don't feel the same).

I also saw [naught](https://github.com/andrewrk/naught) but I can't even start my application via `naught start server.js` -- it doesn't even print anything in stdout / stderr.

I also saw [up-time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/up-time) but I didn't get the idea -- how will it handle situation when I run `gulp` that should replace files in the directory where currently-running instance work at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding of handling replaced files during build: if these files is used by Node.js app then all changes will be applied upon process restart (since these files are loaded into memory), browser frontend files could also be cached in application memory to achieve similar behavior (changes applied only upon restart or/and cache invalidation).

We're using pm2 in cluster mode.

`pm2 start app.js -i`

The above command starts `app.js` in cluster mode on all available CPU cores.

zero downtime restart:

`pm2 gracefulReload all`

this command restarts all processes sequentially, so if you have more than one process up and running there is always at least one process that servers requests during restart.
If you have only one process of `app.js` you can start it in cluster mode and run `pm2 scale app.js 2` (starts one more process) then `pm2 gracefulReload all` and then `pm2 scale app.js 1` (removes previously started process).

Though I think app restarting is not main problem of zero downtime deployment, we've not managed to handle DB migrations, so full app shutdown is needed to apply DB changes. Also there could be an issue with browser frontend files when during deploy user obtained the new version of them, but AJAX request is processed by old version of server process, in this case sticky sessions and API versioning came to the rescue.

Comment: "if these files is used by Node.js app then all changes will be applied upon process restart" -- no, if I rename the `node_modules` and `bower_components` directories, the application will refuse to work

Comment: If Node application is already up and running you can even delete `node_modules` and app will be still up and running (eventually restart will break all). And if you're serving files directly from `node_modules` or `bower_components` then yes - there is a problem. My solution is to cache those files in app memory and serve from there.
So the main idea is to run all build tasks and then gracefully restart the application.

Comment: "And if you're serving files directly from node_modules or bower_components then yes - there is a problem" -- what do you mean by "serving them directly"? I just `require` them in server files and link them via `script` tag in browser files, but I still can't just rename / delete these directories

Comment: I mean "serving directly to browser" <=> "link them via script tag in browser files". Files loaded with `require` in Node.js are stored into memory, so you can do whatever you want with them without any effects to **running** application. To achieve similar functionality for files "linked by script tag" you need to load them into Node.js app's memory and serve them from there to browser, not from FS directly.

Comment: And how it can be achieved?

Comment: I think that the same also goes for views (in my case it is .jade files)

Comment: Just load all the things in memory upon startup and use them from there. I don't know your app configuration and architecture so I can't give you more specific advice.